# Variable resistor wiring

Tags: voltage, current, resistors, resistance, potentiometer

[image]

Hi all, I am very new to electronics. In the diagram shown here, where should I connect the pin of R4 variable resistor.

Comment: Have you read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiometer ? If not, do so now. With just a tiny bit of effort you can understand **how** such a resistor is build and from that figure out how to connect it. Also just measuring one with a multimeter can be very educational.

Comment: "the pin" if your R4 only has one pin you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Show us the picture of your variable resistor. How many pins your variable resistor has?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can see this component like two singles resistors mounted in dividing bridge.
 Admitting you want to divide a 10V supply, the resulting voltage of the divider is in the middle of the potentiometer and the ground (in this case).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw7Lo1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Just connect the wiper terminal to any of the other 2 terminals and you'll be fine. This way, a part of the total resistance gets shorted and current only flow through the rest of it (thus becoming your variable resistor).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQKrpGm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, be careful: when applying a voltage to a potentiometer connected like this, you may easily exceed its current rating if you reduce to much its resistance value. You may want to add a fixed current limiting resistor in series to avoid this.