# Please teach me how to select and use a potentiometer

Tags: potentiometer

The situation: [A 3v to 4.5v pump](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07TJXRVGL), a 9v battery (or a 4.5v 3xAAA holder because I could use either but currently have a 9v in my setup) - hook them up pump moves water. That's as far as I have gotten.

I quickly twigged that this is a terrible idea that will kill my (very cheap) pump. I'd like to control the pump between 3v and 4.5v (ish). So being a total newb I look up variable resistors because that seems like a good idea. Confused by what was on offer, I googled. Today I learned that I have very little understanding. The more I have googled, the less I think I understand.

I learned the most common [variable resistors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/506844/variable-resistors-resistance-value-meaning) are potentiometers. I haven't a clue what ohm(s) I want and how on earth to connect a thing with three connections to my basic battery to pump and back again loop. On this point, I found a similar question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/288295/variable-resistor-wiring) but I was still mystified (possibly because I still find that I struggle to translate what a circuit diagram is showing into how things join up IRL).

Please baby-step me through what I need to understand to select and use a potentiometer for my very basic project.

[Pump in question](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07TJXRVGL) as per request.

**Pump data:**

- Power: 3W
- Voltage: DC 3-4.5V  ( Please keep off over-voltage)
- Current: within 0.05A
- Flow Rate: 100 L/H

Comment: 1st baby step - don't use a potentiometer. 2nd baby step - define the motor, the voltage rating and the maximum current needed to operate it under full load conditions. 3rd baby step - be clear about your battery supply - don't say it's 9 volts then change your mind to 4.5 volts - be clear.

Comment: Could you please provide the link to the datasheet of the pump? Or at very least the link where you bought it?

Can you also explain what you mean to achieve? Why do you want to vary the voltage? Do you need to change the speed of the pump? If not, then there is no need to change the voltage you supply the pump with.

If the pump is 4.5V max, then don't connect it to a 9V battery (it won't survive long). The 3 AAA batteries should be fine for the pump, but I don't expect the batteries to last long.

Comment: this is a Q&A site ... not a tutorial forum ... please ask a question ... for instance, about `The more I have googled, the less I think I understand` ... describe what you think that you are misunderstanding ... ask a question about some aspect of what you found

Comment: It's up to you, as you know as a long-time user of this site and its principles of operation. But you may well get better results from a discussion forum. In the meantime, try googling 'motor speed controller' and look for cheap ones, example circuits using two 555 timers (or a 556) and so on. We can't then comment-discussion you through the next steps but there's plenty out there. Good luck with it.

Comment: A resistance-based speed control is a bad idea for any motor other than *maybe* a fan. And even on fans you have to start them with a lower resistance than they run at (this is why multi-speed box fans have the highest speed immediately adjacent to "off", instead of being on the opposite side, which would probably be more intuitive).

Comment: @jsotola I went from I think I kinda get it to I haven't got a clue - like literally as if I was trying to comprehend War and Peace except it is in an ancient Mesopotamian dialect spoken by 4 people in all of history. I am utterly overwhelmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A potentiometer is a variable resistance. In this case you are suggesting putting it in series with a motor attached to a load (a pump) that typically is quite variable in torque. So it won't work very well as a speed control. The motor will draw lots of current when the torque is high so it will get less voltage and possibly stall before the speed can be reduced much. Although it's seldom a good idea, that would have a better chance of working with something like a fan where the load is steady and goes down as the speed decreases.

I can make some assumptions since you say the pump works from the 4.5V batteries- most importantly that the current draw is << 1A.

Anyway, if you have a battery such as 4.5V or a 5V AC adapter (more likely to be satisfactory unless you only expect the pump to run briefly before you have to go buy or charge more batteries) - you can add series diodes such as 1N4004 and switch to get different speeds. Each diode will drop about 0.6V so 3 will drop the 4.5V down to less than 3V.

Comment: I would expect an inexpensive small pump with an attached motor to be a centrifugal pump with characteristics similar to a fan.

Comment: @CharlesCowie Yes, you're probably right, but also maybe a lot more friction due to shaft seals etc. Could also be a piston pump or a peristaltic metering pump. In any case, constant voltage should be better.

Comment: I was envisioning a cheap hobby pump like an aquarium pump, but those use permanent-magnet AC motors with a wet rotor and encapsulated stator. I found some hobby pumps intended for experiments without continuous use that appear to be centrifugal. Whatever the case, series resistor control would be a reasonable place to start as a learning experience.

Comment: @CharlesCowie I suggest that OP try both.

Comment: I think I can work from this. I will need to ask more questions but you have given me a much-needed kick in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

If the pump ran too fast when connected to a 9-volt battery, it can probably be operated with 3 AA or AAA batteries in series, but the battery life may not be very long. It is not unreasonable to further reduce the speed with a fixed or variable resistor. The resistor should have a power rating close to the power rating of the motor. You need to know rated motor current to guess at resistor values to try. The starting point would be the maximum motor voltage divided by the current that it draws when operating loaded with that voltage applied. The resistor power should be the motor current when loaded, multiplied by the supply voltage. It would be very helpful to have a multimeter.

For a load other than a centrifugal pump or a fan, the resistor would need a higher power rating and the motor performance may be less satisfactory.